# When do I need map reduce for database queries?

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, couchdb, database, nosql

In CouchDB you always have to use map reduce to query results.

In MongoDB you can their query methods for retrieving data, but they also let you do map-reduce.

I wonder, when do I actually need map-reduce?

Are those query methods different from map-reduce or are they just wrappers for map-reduce functions?

Comment: Is this even a question? Map/reduce is an approach to processing that supports parallelism. It's not a special type of function, but an approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MapReduce is needed for aggregations in MongoDB.  The normal queries follow a very different (and much faster) code path and they should always be used for real-time operations.  MapReduce is definitely not intended for real-time, it's more for batch jobs.

Technically, you could write all your queries using MapReduce, but that would be both painful and slow.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was kinda wondering about that as well, whether to use map-reduce for real-time processing because you won't notice this in development.

Comment: You said MapReduce would be PITA to write for every query. Isn't that what you do in CouchDB?